# One GnuPG/PGP key pair, two emails?

Tags: email, gnupg, pgp

I have two emails I use frequently, for both of which I'd like to use PGP keys generated/managed by GnuPG. I'd like to avoid creating a different key pair for each email, if possible, as that's unnecessary for my situation, i.e. I use the two emails interchangeably.

Is there a way to do this?

I am using Mac OS X 10.5 and Ubuntu 11.04, and Thunderbird 3.1.10.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 139, accepted):

If you want to add an user ID to an existing key from the command line (your input is in bold):

```
  $ gpg --edit-key <key-id>
  gpg> adduid
  Real Name: <name>
  Email address: <email>
  Comment: <comment or Return to none>
  Change (N)ame, (C)omment, (E)mail or (O)kay/(Q)uit? O
  Enter passphrase: <password>
  gpg> uid <uid>
  gpg> trust
  Your decision? 5
  Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N) y
  gpg> save
$ gpg --send-keys <key-id>
```

Comment: What does `gpg> uid <uid>` do? Is `<uid>` just my email address `foo@bar.com`?

Comment: @lumeng.dev: is the number right before your new user ID (the list is shown after `adduid`). Once you enter this command, there should be an asterisk near it, indicating that this is the uid `trust` will operate on.

Comment: Do I have to add new identities to the master key pair or can I add new identities directly to subkeys?

Comment: You may also make the old user id the primary user id again by selecting it with `uid <uid>` and making it primary with `primary`.

Comment: The semi-endorsed GUIs like Kleopatra and GPA also have reasonably easy to use controls that perform this action.

Answer (score 14):

Assuming that you use Enigmail for GPG support in Thunderbird, you can simply use the "OpenGPG Security" Tab for each of your identities. You can get there via

```
Account Preferences -> Manage Identities -> Edit.
```

Alternatively, you can select from the Menu:

```
 OpenPGP -> Key Management -> [Right-click on your key] -> Manage User IDs
```

And then add more IDs to your key.

Comment: Don't forget to add an user ID for the second email address to your key, through *OpenPGP -> Manage keys*.

Comment: @grawity, I added this in the edited answer

Comment: Make sure to resend your updated public key to a keyserver

Answer (score 2):

1. Install kgpg
2. Select your key
3. Right click --> Add User Id